# Is cppreference using the term "[Object's] identity" is two different meanings for c++11 and for c++17?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++17, value-categories

I thought I've managed to fully understand (with the help of other SO questions, thanks) the C++17's change regarding value categories, but now I've noticed this problem which suggests I don't really understand them.

In C++11, there was a "has identity / can be moved from" interpretation of value categories and the definition of what "identity" means is still present in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

> has identity: it's possible to determine whether the expression refers to the same entity as another expression, such as by comparing addresses of the objects or the functions they identify (obtained directly or indirectly).

In C++17, "has identity / can be moved from" is no longer true, but the new definition is also based on the concept of "identity":

> a glvalue (“generalized” lvalue) is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object, bit-field, or function;

My question/misunderstanding is: is this the same meaning of "identity", or is it a different "identity"? The way I understand it, the situation in c++17 is as follows:

```
A f() { return A(); }

A a = f(); // 1: f() is a prvalue expression, used to directly initialize a.
f();       // 2: f() is a prvalue expr., converted to xvalue by temporary materialization
A&& r = f(); // 3: f() is a prvalue expr., converted to xvalue by temporary materialization
```

In the 2nd and 3rd case, I obtain an xvalue, which means it should have an identity. So I should be able to <strike>get its address</strike> [edited:] I should be able to determine whether it refers to the same entity as some other expression, but I don't think I can. Of course, in the 3rd case I'm able to do "&r" as a separate command and then compare its address to the other expression's address, but that's because A&& is an lvalue. Is taking the address via A&& what they mean in this case by "obtained directly or indirectly"? I assumed this can't be the correct answer, because in C++11 I can also easily do

```
A&& r = f(); // 4: f() is a prvalue expression. Temporary materialization does
             // not happen, the temporary (prvalue) gets its lifetime 
             // extended to match the lifetime of the reference
&r;
```

and yet the object referenced by r is still a temporary despite having its lifetime extended, and in c++11 temporaries are prvalues. So I assume just the fact I can bind A&& to it (of which, like any lvalue, I can take an address but only in a separate expression) is not enough to conclude that its evaluation determines an identity (after all, whatever happens in the line "&r;" is not part of an evaluation of my original expression), and yet in c++17 it looks to me like this would be the only possible interpretation?

Can you help me by determining which part of what I wrote is incorrect? Or is it correct, and the answer is simply that the word "identity" has changed its meaning?

Comment: Your question is based on the assumption that _"I obtain an xvalue, which means it should have an identity. So I should be able to get its address"_ is true and this is obvious to everyone. But this looks like opinion to me.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Both of those come from Cppreference, not from myself, so why do you think they are opinions? 1) "a glvalue is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity" 2) "has identity: it's possible to determine whether the expression refers to the same entity as another expression, such as by comparing addresses of the objects or the functions they identify (obtained directly or indirectly)." -----

Let's take 2nd or 3rd line from my post: How can I "determine whether the expression refers to the same entity as another expression"? Cppreference guarantees I can, for xvalues.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Which xvalues don't have an identity?

Comment: What makes you say that temporary objects are *values?

Comment: @curiousguy "has identity == should be able to get address" seem true to you too?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Obviously not if you mean "apply address of operator". But something that has an identity at least conceptually occupies a memory location with an address (in the abstract - it may be in a register if no address is exported).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer "_seem true to you too_" If it doesn't to you, can you provide a counter example?

Comment: @curiousguy `&static_cast<int&&>(0)`

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Good point but then when you name it, you can obtain its address, right? I don't have a good intuitive grasp on these rules...

Comment: @curiousguy _I don't have a good intuitive grasp on these rules_ Those intuitive rules like "named references are lvalues, unnamed aren't" were always enraging me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think that the C++11 concepts no longer apply?  The page says that that version introduced the “has identity” idea, not that it’s the only version that uses it.  What C++17 did was say that prvalues “wait until” they are used for initialization of an object to become an object at all.  (It therefore merges “being an object” with “having identity”, which is simpler; plainly every object can have `this` be detected.)

What that really means is that the address of that target object is invisibly passed to the site of the prvalue construction so that it appears in the correct place from the start.  Compilers were already doing that under the RVO name, but the change guaranteed that and removed formal movability restrictions.

The xvalue certainly has an identity: if you pass a prvalue to a function by (either kind of) reference, it can take its address.  It can even return it so that (during the same full-expression) the function that created it can use its address.  The prohibition on taking the address of a temporary is a separate safety measure that applies even after (say) using `static_cast<A&&>(get_a())` to force temporary materialization.  (However, it can’t stop you from taking the address of a glvalue that refers to the temporary returned from another function.)

Comment: "Copy elision" was never about suppressing a copy and all about lifetime fusion and constructing stuff at the right place. The "copy elision" term stuck, though.

Comment: @krzysztofk: `&&` does bind to prvalues in the sense that they are automatically converted to xvalues if you try; that’s enough to satisfy “can be moved from”.  It is true that an expression (but not an *id-expression*) whose type was `T&&` before adjustment is an xvalue.  The invisible address is used in practice only for “non-trivial” class types (as defined by the ABI); this is unobservable because you can’t learn an address quickly enough without examining `this` in a non-trivial constructor.

Comment: Thanks :) The reasons why I wrote C++11 concepts no longer apply were twofold, of which one part you cleared up to me with your answer. One reason is that if I understand correctly, the C++11 concept of "it is rvalue = it can be moved from" is no longer true because prvalues can't be moved from anymore. Likewise, I can't anymore say "it's rvalue = it's possible to bind && to it", because && doesn't bind to prvalues. So basically if I understand this right, && should now be called an "xvalue reference" if not for historical reasons, because it binds to xvalues and to nothing more than xvalues

Comment: [continued] 2nd reason (the one you cleared up to me) is that I wasn't aware that the definition of "identity" became basically meaningless now, because like you said "object with identity" and "object" now mean exactly the same. In C++11, some of the objects didn't have an identity (namely: the temporaries) while now all the objects must have an identity, which was the reason why I thought (having the old meaning still in mind) "is glvalue = has identity" doesn't apply. But as you say the definition of "object with identity" is now different and equals to simply "object", it indeed applies.

Comment: [continued] One last question. When you cay "What that really means is that the address of that target object is invisibly passed to the site of the prvalue construction " - I was aware that in practice compilers solve it this way for objects, but is it OK if from your answer I understand that this also actually the "Real Truth"? That is, is this sentence true and guaranteed for all prvalues always (including built-in types), or is it just one (but not the only) way of how compilers deal with it in practice?

Comment: @DavisHerring Great, I think I've truly understood it now, thank you!